# FirebaseUI & SDWebImage Displaying Image in a for loop in a CollectionViewControllerCell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

Is it possible to set the images for my image view inside of a for loop ? 
I am currently getting all my image download urls from the firebase database and i saved them in a Dictionary of type [[String: Any]]

Inside of the cellforItemAt Method of my CollectionViewControllerFile I am currently calling a for loop like this:

```
   override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyImageCell

    for myurl in urlArray {
        print("Hier kommt myURL \(myurl)")
    let url = URL(string: myurl["url"] as! String)
        cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
    }

    cell.myLabel?.text  = "test"

    return cell
}
```

But this way only the last image is displayed 5 times.

I created a custom cell and created a class for it right here:

```
class MyImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

}
```

Im am creating 1 Section and 5 Items per Section. Is it even possible to use SDWebImage inside a for loop or what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
let item = urlArray[indexPath.row]       
let url = URL(string: item["url"] as! String)
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: url, completed: nil)
```

Every call to `cellForItemAt` returns a cell so everytime you finally set the last url of your array to the imageView , also you should create a model like

```
struct Root {
  let url:URL
  // add more properties 
}
```

then create an array of it like

```
var myArray = [Root]()
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot!